# Mocking frameworks for Pharo

Tags: mocking, pharo

What are the different alternatives to write mock-based unit tests for [Pharo](http://www.pharo.org) today? What are the pros and cons of each?

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Mocketry](http://smalltalkhub.com/#!/~dionisiy/Mocketry) which provides a nice DSL

Comment: I'm looking for some documentation about it, is there anything besides the readme? Also, is it possible to mock/stub a single method from an existing object?

Answer (score 0):

BabyMock2 provides nice visualizations. There is a [Fosdem video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xChlI4j4Euc) of it